# How to make this R function faster

Tags: r

Under R, i implemented this function to train SOM map :

```
  kohonen_map <- function(data=iris[,-5],data_classes=iris$Species, neighborhood_fun="gaussian", learning_rate=0.01, distance_type="euclidean", sigma=0.1, num_neurons = 3, num_iterations = 100) {

    
    # initialize the map weights randomly
    map_weights <- t(sapply(split(data[, 1:4], data_classes), colMeans))
    
    # initialize the radius and learning rate decay
    radius <- num_neurons / 2
    learning_rate_decay <- 0.9
    
    # define the distance function
    switch(distance_type,
           "euclidean" = distance_fun <- function(x, y) return(sqrt(rowSums((x - y)^2))),
           "manhattan" = distance_fun <- function(x, y) return(rowSums(abs(x - y))),
           "cosine" = distance_fun <- function(x, y) return(1 - rowSums(x * y) / (sqrt(rowSums(x^2)) * sqrt(rowSums(y^2)))),
           stop("Invalid distance type. Supported values are euclidean, manhattan, and cosine."))
    
    # define the neighborhood kernel function
    switch(neighborhood_fun,
           "gaussian" = neighborhood_kernel <- function(i, j) return(exp(-((i - j) / sigma)^2)),
           "circular" = neighborhood_kernel <- function(i, j) return(as.numeric(abs(i - j) <= radius)),
           stop("Invalid neighborhood function. Supported values are gaussian and circular."))
    
    # iterate over the data
    for (i in 1:num_iterations) {
      
      # iterate over the data
      for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
        
        # compute the distance between the data point and each neuron
        distances <- distance_fun(map_weights, data[j,])
        
        # find the winning neuron
        winning_neuron <- which.min(distances)
        
        # compute the neighborhood kernel
        neighborhood_factors <- neighborhood_kernel(winning_neuron, 1:num_neurons)
        
       #dput(neighborhood_factors)
       #dput(as.matrix(data[j,]))
       #dput(map_weights)
        
        #break
        
        # update the weights of the winning neuron and its neighbors
        map_weights <- map_weights + learning_rate * neighborhood_factors * (as.numeric(data[j,]) - as.matrix(map_weights))
        
      }
      
      # update the radius and learning rate
      radius <- radius * learning_rate_decay
      learning_rate <- learning_rate * learning_rate_decay
    }
    
    # predict the class of each observation
    predicted_classes <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {
      distances <- distance_fun(map_weights, x)
      which.min(distances)
    })
    
    # plot the convergence graphics
    #plot(1:length(predicted_classes), predicted_classes, type = "l", xlab = "Iteration", ylab = "Predicted class")
    
    # return the predicted classes
    return(predicted_classes)
  }
```

Example of running :

```
library("caret")
predicted_classes <- kohonen_map()


confusionMatrix(unique(iris[,5])[c(predicted_classes)],iris[,5])
```

The problem i have is that code is very slow ( due to distance computation ).

Thanks for help

Comment: Please edit to include all libraries in use.   Also, it's imperative that you show **how** you have identified the "slowest" part of your function.      As a side note, you invoke `iris_classes`  inside your function but do not provide any such variable in your function inputs.   Thus if your `data` is not `iris` something will probably go very wrong.

Comment: To speed up avoid the rowwise calculation. In theory with those math methods, you could run function on entire data. Where do you use `i`? I do not immediately see randomness so it is unclear what changes across `iterations`. So you repeat same inner loop `i` number of times. Run inner loop once and use result in a vectorized iteration `i` times elsewhere.

Comment: Your use of `switch` is very unconventional, and while it might work, the use of `<-` assignment _inside_ of each expression is a bit fragile. I suggest `distance_fun <- switch(.., a=function(...) ...)` instead, it is easier to read/maintain and less fragile (and more conventional). I second the argument _against_ rowwise operations.

Comment: @Parfait > Could you provide how to do in this case ? Thanks